# CSS on select tag in modal is not working using zurb foundation

Tags: css, reactjs, zurb-foundation

I am using `foundation` for styling my react component. I have a form which contain User Role filed to be selected from dropdown. I am rendering user form in modal, I am not using form tag for my form.

When I open the form the select tag losing its css, question is simple but not able to find anywhere.

I am rendering modal just above from the `</body>` tag. Input text field is properly style, please check the image.[image]

```
<div id="user_creation_form" class="reveal-modal open" style="top: 304px; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; display: block;">
  <div data-react-class="UserForm" class="edit-modal-1">
    <div data-reactroot="" class="user-form">
      <div>
        <h3 class="subheader"></h3>
        <div class="user-form">
          <h4>User Information</h4>
          <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="field dropdown">
                <label>User Role</label>
                <select>
                  <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                  <option value="user">User</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-section-divider"></div>
          <div>
            <h4>Authentication Method</h4>
            <div class="auth-container">
              <ul class="auth-methods">
                <li class="auth-methods--selector ">Email</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="field">
              <label>Full Name</label>
              <span class="optionalLabel">(Optional)</span>
               <input type="text" value="dsjdfksdjaflkdsjlafjdlskaklfds">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label>Email</label>
              <span class="optionalLabel">(Optional)</span>
              <input type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="action-buttons">
            <div class="button radius submit-button">
              Update User
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="close-reveal-modal">×</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The image is beautiful, but it's impossible to tell what might be wrong without the actual code. Could you make a snippet?

Comment: Did you put "class" instead of "className"?  Use the browser developer tools to inspect the element and see if the right class is assigned, or what CSS is being applied

Comment: Yes I put className and also I tried with `custom` class but unable to find the cause of issue.

Comment: Updated my question with the `HTML` I got from developer tool.